# Is there a database for non time series data sets?

Tags: dataset

I am searching for some data sets that would be suitable for regression analysis that my teacher wants for Statistical Learning lesson's homework. But as I search I only encounter with time series data.

Q: Does anybody familiar with such websites that I can download ***Non-time series data with enough dimensions*** to do regression analysis?

Any help with be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Gosh there is huge number of open-source datasets out there. To start, visit,

http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/

This UCI repo has 350 datasets of all variety for testing different machine learning algorithms.

Another one :

http://rs.io/100-interesting-data-sets-for-statistics/

EDIT :

Here is an even bigger list, organized by category, covering a broad spectrum of interests,

https://github.com/caesar0301/awesome-public-datasets

Comment: You saved me man! The is Exactly What I want :) Sorry I gave +1 But after my reputation grown It will count to your answer. Thanks.